# What is the correct url for calling task in the backend controller

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development, joomla-api, ajax

I'm developing my custom component and I need to call some task from back-end controller during editing a single record. The url of my record edit page in the back-end is:

```
.../administrator/index.php?option=com_mycom&view=page&layout=edit&id=2
```

There is my ajax-query for calling a task in the record controller:

```
$.ajax({
 method: "POST",
 cache: false,
 url: 'index.php?option=com_mycom&task=deleteimg&format=raw&id=<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>',
 data: {id: '<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>'}
}).done(function() {
 alert('Deleted');
});
return false;
```

I tried also the urls:

```
index.php?option=com_mycom&controller=record&task=deleteimg&format=raw&id=...
index.php?option=com_mycom&controller=record&view=record&layout=edit&task=deleteimg&format=raw&id=...
```

But every time console displays me the 404 error:

> POST ...//domain.com/administrator/index.php?...&id=2 404 (...
>   [name, type, prefix]: pages, raw, mycomView)

What the correct url should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
index.php?option=com_mycom&task=yourcontroller.deleteimg&tmpl=component&id=<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>
```